# Locale error when building Petalinux project

Tags: locale, xilinx

I am trying to build petalinux project but I faced this error

```
    shaden@shaden-Swift:~/Documents/PetalinuxProjects/1/xilinx-zcu102-2018.2$ petalinux-build
[INFO] building project
[INFO] sourcing bitbake
INFO: bitbake petalinux-user-image
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

    You system needs to support the en_US.UTF-8 locale.

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
ERROR: Failed to build project
```

locale output

```
shaden@shaden-Swift:~/Documents/PetalinuxProjects/1/xilinx-zcu102-2018.2$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I tried (export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8") but not solve the error.

my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Petalinux version 2018.2

Any one know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you are running this on a Ubuntu machine but I do not see anything Ubuntu related in this question.

Comment: @David It's a set of tools for Linux products development. It's no different than any other software running in Ubuntu and on-topic.

Comment: I would stop setting `LC_ALL`. That variable does not need to be set persistently. Ever. `LANG` is sufficient.,

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson 
thank you for your answer
I do it but still the same error
I did it by ( export LC_ALL="")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an incompatibility between Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (probably some updated library) and the Python 3.5 included in Yocto / PetaLinux.

The workaround is to edit the ".../usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py" file(s) and make the setlocale() function fail quietly:

```
def setlocale(category, locale=None):
 
    """ Set the locale for the given category.  The locale can be
        a string, an iterable of two strings (language code and encoding),
        or None.
 
        Iterables are converted to strings using the locale aliasing
        engine.  Locale strings are passed directly to the C lib.
 
        category may be given as one of the LC_* values.
 
    """
    if locale and not isinstance(locale, _builtin_str):
        # convert to string
        locale = normalize(_build_localename(locale))
    try:
        return _setlocale(category, locale)
    except:
        pass
```

https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpjH7/petalinux-build-fails-with-locale-errors-how-to-disable-locale-checks?language=en_US